# consIDered as a beauty

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, visual

**What's the 14-letter answer I'm looking for?**

---

```
                                                               ((||| - (—— —— |||)), | —— |||||
—— —— —— —— ——  |  ——   —— —— ——  (||||| - (—— —— —— —— |||||))                                ||| —— —— ——, |||, —— ——   —— —— —— ——, | —— ||||| —— —— —— —— ——
```

---

```
          X X X X X X X X X X
          X X X X X X X X X X
          X X X X X X X X X X
          X X X X X X X X X X
          X X X X X X X X X X
 X X X X X                   X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X
 X X X X X                   X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X
 X X X X X                   X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X
 X X X X X                   X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X
 X X X X X                   X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X X
```

---

Comment: From the title and the X's I know the answer. Not sure how the dashes and pipes work though...

Comment: @cap Ah, should've used a more cryptic title. I was actually unsure if I should use that title but hoped it wouldn't make too much sense. The problem with titles sometimes... But keep trying to make sense how they work

Comment: it was the X's I recognized first and the title merely confirmed it. Working on it...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The 14-letter answer is:

> [**EULER'S IDENTITY**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_identity) - the name given to the equation $e^{i\pi}+1=0$ which is considered an example of 'mathematical beauty' (hence the title, which also emphasises 'ID' for 'identity').

The general shape of this can be seen in the arrangement of Xs:

> If an individual character is 5 Xs high and wide then we have an arrangement consisting of 1 character, 2 characters at a higher level (superscript), and 4 characters at the same level as the first - exactly as the formula does.

And, in fact, this observation is key to decoding the remainder of the puzzle...

> Let's split up the Xs into the seven 5x5 character blocks and assign each row and column within a character block a number from 1 to 5, beginning the numbering from the top-left corner:
>
>  [image: Dividing the image into numbered cells with a coordinate system]
>
>  Now count up the number of bar (|) and dash (—) symbols in any given comma-separated run of symbols, and interpret these as representing 'column number [x]' or 'row number [y]'. **Shade these columns or rows.** Occasionally, a term appears with a subtraction sign; in these instances, what follows is a combination of bars and dashes suggesting an individual cell that should *not* be shaded in that column/row.

This may be tricky to understand at first reading, so here's an explanation of each term in the bar/dash sequences:

```
—— —— —— —— ——  |  ——   —— —— ——  (||||| - (—— —— —— —— |||||))
```

> row5, col1, row1, row3, col5 without r4c5

*At the higher level:*

```
((||| - (—— —— |||))
```

> col3 without r2c3

```
| —— |||||
```

> col1, row1, col5

*Returning to 'regular level':*

```
||| —— —— ——
```

> col3, row3

```
|||
```

> col3

```
—— ——   —— —— —— ——
```

> row2, row4

```
| —— ||||| —— —— —— —— ——
```

> col1, row1, col5, row5

Highlighting/shading just the cells indicated here results in the following image:

> [image: Euler's identity revealed in the image]
>
>  In other words, Euler's identity, $e^{i\pi}+1=0$, is revealed for all to see!

Comment: Solved :) Nicely explained and great job!